# Java Fill preallocated File with Data (on drive)

Tags: java, file, allocation, diskspace

i want to download a videofile from the web. It is 121 MB. Now i want to pre allocate this 121 MB on the disk (with zeros or what ever) and fill it step by step with the data of the inputstream from the urlconnection. Or with other words: It doesn't matter how much has been downloaded yet - the file size is always the destinated 121MB.

Is it possible?
thank you

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you're unlikely to get answer if you don't try first.

Comment: I know that i can create an empty file of a specific size. But if i write data to this dummyfile (via fileoutputstream) it will be overwritten and it's size becomes updated to the current downloaded data.

Comment: why not?  just open the file and write your zeros/filler data (easy for loop).

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution. First of all i write the empty dummy file and then i reopen the empty file and replace the bytes:

```
    System.out.println("Writing dummy ...");
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    for (int size = 0; size < fileLength; size += buf.length) {
        out.write(buf);
        out.flush();
    }
    out.close();

    System.out.println("Writing data ...");
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(temp, "rw");
    int count = 0;
    long total = 0;
    while ((count = stream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        raf.seek(total);
        raf.write(buf);
        total += count;
    }
    raf.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Obviously. Create file, write loop that writes 121*1024*1024 bytes to this file. You can either write byte-by-byte or using chunks. Chunks are preferable from performance perspective.

Here is the demo code:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]; // 1KB array.
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFilePath);
for (int size = 0; size < 121*1024*1024; size += bytes.length;) {
    os.write(b);
    os.flush();
}
os.close();
```

Comment: thank you for the fast reply but that is not what i meant. i want to create a "container" (the file that is filled with nothing) and fill it up with the videodata. I want the file to be 121MB even it isn't downloaded yet.