# How to Get reference of Opened file in Java?

Tags: java, filehandle

I want to build a method that opens an existing file and returns a reference to said file (Like a file handle) as an object. If I succeed in opening this file, then the fields of the file handle should be initialized with the information about the opened file, like for example the number of blocks stored in that file. Any Idea how to go about this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a new class to hold all the fields you need.

Comment: The `File`, `FileInputStream`, and `FileReader` classes already exist, and you don't need to open a file to get its metadata. And what does this have to do with [tag:database]?

Comment: @EJP It's for a mini-Database project for my second database class, Failed to mention that I apologize. Thanks for your reply appreciate it.

Comment: Define "reference". Have a look at `Paths.get()` and `Files`. And please, no, not `File` in 2016.

Comment: @fge Reference as File name, number of blocks, current block position, that sort of thing. I Followed a link that was posted and found alot of helpful methods that made me understand. I'm curious though, why not use File? Is it outdated, inefficient, what? I'm interested to know.

Comment: None of that block information about files is available in Java.

Comment: @EJP Hmmm, okay, another question if you don't mind. Is there a way to reserve space in a file in order to store certain information in it? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

```
File fileReference = new File("/path/to/your/file");
if (fileReference.isFile()) {
  long length = fileReference.length();
  // etc.
}
```

See more available methods on the File class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Please. No. Not in 2016. There is JSR 203.

Comment: Thanks for the link, helped me out, I appreciate it. Can I add to my question? Is their a way to reserve space at the start of the file? Like to store certain information, and said information would be the length, name of the file etc.?

Comment: Sure, this previous post seems to answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588142/java-fill-preallocated-file-with-data-on-drive

If you consider that I have answered your original question, please mark the answer as "accepted".